# Does plugging in headphones to iphone Deactivate the internal mic of iphone?

Tags: iphone, headphones

While you are talking on the iphone, if you plug in your headphones (with NO mic), does the iphone internal mic become inactive and you can't talk into it until you take out the headphones? Or does the mic remain active?

Comment: Ring someone & see

Answer (score 1):

The Internal mic will only disable if headphones with a supported mic are attached to the phone. I would attach an apple link explaining this...but one only exists for Mac!